# Has anyone compared the two Sparkpost extension?

Tags: civimail, sparkpost

Two Sparkpost extensions for Civimail have been released/updated in the last couple of days.

1. https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost
2. https://github.com/proexchange/com.pesc.sparkpost

   Has anyone compared them to see which works best?

Answer (score 4):

I've used them both. CiviDesk's version wins hands down on ease of installation as you just install and plug in your API from SparkPost. Also if I understand it, sending via the API is preferred.

PESC's version requires installation, update SMTP settings with those provided by SparkPost, and then configuring a Scheduled Job with API and other configuration settings.

One issue I am noticing on a site with CiviDesk's module is a [high bounce rate reported in CiviCRM](https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost/issues/17) (bounces of type "Syntax") which are not actual bounces in SparkPost - but I may not have had the latest version. Testing now.

Comment: I am also currently experiencing the high "bounce" rate for "syntax" with the cividesk extension - but I was not able to get bulk mail sending out using the pesc extension (transactional mail not through civiMail was fine), not sure what I had misconfigured but it did seem more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with the com.pesc extension but the Cividesk worked "out of the box" on Drupal. I'm testing over the weekend and will post feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your mileage may vary.  I tried the cividesk extension first and could not get it to work despite many tries.  Then I switched to the pesc extension and found that it works perfectly.  The setup on the pesc version is a little more involved, but it is not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Curious to know if anyone has any updates to their experience with both.  I plan to install now.  Will share my experience too.

Comment: I used the com.pesc and it worked, no problems.  Instructions were complete and easy to follow.  I selected this plugin because of the reports of high bounce rate with the other option.

Comment: I have just installed the CiviDesk extension on 4.7 with Wordpress. It worked out of the box, and finally now CiviCRM Mailings are working! Great Job CiviDesk folks! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Both extensions worked for me for CiviMail and Transactional Mail. PESC worked a bit better but more configuration required. CiviDesk was not processing bounce backs for me. Once I configured PESC it was getting the Bounces back. If you use the PESC extension remember to remove the - optional and - required from the API Bounce configuration once you had included your API key in the scheduled jobs.